# How do I merge multiple columns together with the same name keeping the highest value each time?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have lots of columns about film data that look like this as a pandas dataframe:

```
 Film     Action, Action, Adventure, Adventure, Biography, Action, Comedy .....
 title1       1      0        0         1          0         0        0   
 title2       0      1        0         0          1         0        1
```

This list gets very long

What I want to do is have each genre only once but if any of the columns with the genre name have a one in them then keep them not the 0 so essentially keep the genre column with the highest value.

please note, there are other columns such as "filmLength", rating etc that I haven't bothereed to include in this.

So the expected output would look like this:

```
film     Action       Adventure        Biography        Comedy
title1      1              1                0               0
title2      1              0                1               1
```

Comment: Why do you have commas everywhere? Have you properly read your csv file into pandas?

Comment: I did that manually just to make it easier to read

Comment: It's the wrong way. Delete all commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to group the columns of the same label by adding them. `If-else` is necessary to distinguish when there is more than one column or not. The `sum(axis = 1)` operation would throw an error for `Series` (when there is no repetition) if the `if-else` statement was not used:

```
new_df=pd.concat([df[col].sum(axis=1).rename(col) if len(df[col].shape)==2 else df[col] for col in df.columns.unique()],axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
     Film  Action  Adventure  Biography  Comedy
0  title1       1          1          0       0
1  title2       1          0          1       1
```

**Details:**

[Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)  is used to obtain the names of the labels of the columns without repetitions:

```
df.columns.unique()

Index(['Film', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Biography', 'Comedy'], dtype='object')
```

---

Then the columns that have the same label name are selected by means of a for loop:

```
for col in df.columns.unique()
```

The idea is to add the values ​​of the columns that are repeated for each row using df [col] .sum (axis = 1).
[rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) is used to assign the name of the repeated column to the series resulting from the sum. This way the name will not be lost:

```
df[col].sum(axis=1).rename(col) for col in df.columns.unique()
```

if there is only one column with the name `Adventure` for example.
the sum operation `(axis = 1)` will give an error because this operation is not attributable to a series, since a series has only one axis. So you should only use this operation when it is the case of a repeated column.
Then to distinguish between the two cases it is used:

```
df[col].sum(axis=1).rename(col) if len(df[col].shape)==2 else df[col] for col in df.columns.unique()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but could you please add a bit more explanation as not 100% sure I understand what your code is actually doing.